# how to update a container in java that already has data in it

Tags: java, user-interface, button, containers, grid-layout

Hi all i need to update a containers data for a sudoku game i am creating but am struggling to  get the field to update with the new data.the container uses a grid layout and each cell contains a button with the appropriate number for sudoku in it and i need to know how to update the text in these buttons. any help with what methods i could use or any help in general would be greatly appreciated. please see the code i currently have to try and update below i know its probably messy and completely on the wrong track but ive just been trying to mess with stuff hoping it would work.

```
public void update(int[][] grid2)throws NullPointerException{
myGrid = new Container();
try{
  for(int i = 0; i<9; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j<9; j++){
      String appropriateNumber = convertSimple(grid2[i][j]);
      JButton button = new JButton(appropriateNumber);
      button.addActionListener(new sudokuListener());
      myGrid.add(button);
    }
  }
}
catch(NullPointerException e){

}
myGrid.setLayout(new GridLayout(9, 9));
myGrid.setPreferredSize (new Dimension(400, 400));

add(myGrid);
puzzleGUI.update();
}
```

puzzlGUI.update simply contains puzzle.validate() (puzzle being the GUI)

[edit]
ok i have changed things around a bit and used the JButton arrya as suggested and i have been able to set the text of the buttons in this array (i know through a system.out.print) but this does not update the text which is in the actual GUI. aaaaahhh coding is not fun at the end of a semester please help anyone

Comment: Rather than add new JButtons/components to your grid, why not simply iterate through the components that are already in the grid and update their state, such as perhaps by changing the text showing on the JButtons? If this doesn't help, then please consider telling us more about your current program. Assume that we have no prior knowledge of what it does or how it is supposed to work.

Comment: As @HovercraftFullOfEels says, plus: call `repaint()` not `update()`, and try not to mix AWT components with Swing components (ie favour `JPanel` (or similar) instead of `Component`.

Comment: similarly to the code i have there, earlier in the program that is how i added the buttons initially and as such dont have a way to access them (in my knowledge)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To re-iterate, if you have a grid of JButtons, why re-create them every time? Why not simply iterate through the components that are already in the grid and update their state, such as perhaps the text showing on the JButtons?

```
  for(int i = 0; i<9; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j<9; j++){
      String appropriateNumber = convertSimple(grid2[i][j]);
      someButtonArray[i][j].setText(appropriateNumber);

      // no longer need this stuff
      // JButton button = new JButton(appropriateNumber);
      // button.addActionListener(new sudokuListener());
      // myGrid.add(button);
    }
  }
```

Comment: thanks once i got my head around it i managed to fix errors in my code and its all working now appreciate the help

Answer (score 1):

Your update method is creating new Swing components every time it is called which is unnecessary if you just need to update the text. To directly update the text in any `JButton` you could create a button array like so:

```
JButton[][]  buttons = new JButton[9][9];
```

and create like this (called only once):

```
for (int i = 0; i<9; i++) {
   for(int j = 0; j < 9; j++){
      String appropriateNumber = convertSimple(grid2[i][j]);
      button[i][j] = new JButton(appropriateNumber);
      button[i][j].addActionListener(new sudokuListener());
      myGrid.add(button[i][j]);
    }
}
```

then to update :

```
buttons[row][column].setText("New Text");
```